# Civilization Beyond Earth -How do I change a quest decision?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I got Civ-BE about a week ago.  I cannot figure out how to change a quest decisions. Building outposts is on the list but I can't change what the game thinks I should quest for.

Comment: If you have two unrelated questions, ask them as separate questiosn.

Comment: I've edited your question to only include the part Shadur answered. Feel free to ask the deleted part as a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

Once made, a quest decision is locked in and can't be changed except by reloading a save from before you made it and choosing differently when the decision comes up.

Choose wisely.

Comment: But I didn't make the decision. The quest list is presented with the decision already marked.

Comment: @ChuckBerridge: Can you post a screenshot to your question in order to highlight exactly what you are referring to?

Comment: No need to. The whole thing stemmed from my misunderstanding of how the tech web works and what the quests log was telling me. I thought that researching Habitation gave me the leaves under it. No pioneering, no outposts. I also thought that un unchecked box in the quests log meant I could select it.

Comment: Civ-BE has some similarities to Masters of Orion, but it is so much better.